# How to create multi-dimensional array from a list?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a list of categories in MySQL with parent ID. How can I create a PHP array from the list.

```
ID  Category      Parent_ID
1   Car           NULL
2   Education     NULL
3   Mathematics   2
4   Physics       2
5   Astrophysics  4
```

I want to produce an array of this structure

```
array(
    "Car" => "1",
    "Education" => array("Mathematics" => "2", "Physics" => array("Astrophysics" => "4"))
);
```

As a matter of fact, key/value is not important as I will work with other columns too. I just want to know how to scan the list and produce multi-level list.

Comment: what s your key to array? how do you want your array to look? do you want assoc. array? or you want to store each row as an object?

Comment: I added a sample array to the question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some very simple recursion to build a tree structure:

```
function buildTree(array $data, $parent = null) {
    $branch = array();

    foreach ($data as $row) {
        if ($row['parent_id'] == $parent) {
            $row['children'] = buildTree($data, $row['id']);
            $branch[] = $row;
        }
    }

    return $branch;
}

$tree = buildTree($rowsFromDatabase);
```

Having an explicit `'children'` key is usually preferable to the structure you're proposing, but feel free to modify as needed.

Comment: `$parent = null` should be `$parent = ""` mysql returns empty string for null values. Other than that +1.

Comment: @Louis You're right. It'll still work correctly though, since we're only comparing loosely. :)

Comment: @deceze You can do this with [one loop](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11240578/697154) only, no need for n*n loops. ;)