# Custom post type taxonomy navigation

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I've a custom post type and a custom taxonomy assigned to it. I'm trying to get the categories to display in following manner.

Use: When you hover on the Parent category with child items it should display child items and the same for sub items for child category.

[image]

I tried using wp_list_categories() function but it returns the list in following order.

[image]

How do I get this to match the screenshot 1 layout?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion it is possible to build the tree like parent->child structure to any level. You might need to build that custom function. Have a look at the below example which uses recursion.

[Creating a recursive category tree function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12285694/creating-a-recursive-category-tree-function)