# Converting PHP Array into ExtJS TreePanel Format

Tags: php, cakephp, extjs

My database spits out an hierarchy array of data like this:

```
Array(
    [0] => array(
        [level] => 0
        [wo_number] => foo1
        [parent] => NULL
    )
    [1] => array(
        [level] => 1
        [wo_number] => foo2
        [parent] => foo1
    )
    [2] => array(
        [level] => 2
        [wo_number] => bar1
        [parent] => foo2
    )
    [3] => array(
        [level] => 2
        [wo_number] => bar2
        [parent] => foo2
    )
    [4] => array(
        [level] => 2
        [wo_number] => bar3
        [parent] => foo2
    )
    [5] => array(
        [level] => 2
        [wo_number] => bar4
        [parent] => foo2
    )
    [6] => array(
        [level] => 2
        [wo_number] => bar5
        [parent] => foo2
    )
)
```

Each array node has a parent key that references another node in the array.

And I need to convert the array to a format like this:

```
Array(
    [0] => array(
        [level] => 0
        [wo_number] => foo1
        [parent] => NULL
        [children] => array(
            [0] => array(
                [level] => 1
                [wo_number] => foo2
                [parent] => foo1
                [children] => array(
                    etc etc etc
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

So that I can then json_encode it, and use it in a ExtJS TreePanel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Create a Multidimensional Array from an array with relational data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239652/php-create-a-multidimensional-array-from-an-array-with-relational-data)

Comment: Why not just store the JSON data directly in a NoSQL database? You would eliminate any need for transformation.

Comment: your db does NOT return an array, you are formatting the db results that way with php, so change how you do that

Comment: Yoshi comment is very similar. Except when I run that makeRecursive function, it only returns the first child on down. But it is very similar to my needs. I just wish the makeRecursive() was human-readable :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a slighlty changed function (from what I linked in the comments):

```
/**
 * Helper function
 * 
 * @param array  $d flat data, implementing a id/parent id (adjacency list) structure
 * @param mixed  $r root id, node to return
 * @param string $p parent id index
 * @param string $k id index
 * @param string $c children index
 * @return array
 */
function flat2nested($d, $r = 0, $p = 'parent', $k = 'id', $c = 'children') {
  $m = array();
  foreach ($d as $e) {
    isset($m[$e[$p]]) ?: $m[$e[$p]] = array();
    isset($m[$e[$k]]) ?: $m[$e[$k]] = array();
    $m[$e[$p]][] = array_merge($e, array($c => &$m[$e[$k]]));
  }

  return $m[$r]; // removed the `[0]` here
}
```

You can go with an easy call, such as:

```
flat2nested($input, null, $p = 'parent', $k = 'wo_number');
```

though currently no `leaf` index would be set, but as this seems to allways be `false` it would be easier to set it in the input array.

demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/IKRLUO

If you have questions about the inner workings of `flat2nested` (or `makeRecursive`) just leave a comment and I'll extend my answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my unnecessary loop at the end and just returning $m[$r] as the children. I have updated my function above to what I am using now.

Comment: Is there a nested2flat() one as well up your sleeve?

Comment: @Pyrite Well, that would be a standard [tree traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) problem. For which there are many good methods readily available.

Comment: Yea, I see that now. I ended up making one in Javascript to only get the data I need from the tree.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the makeRecursive() function that Yoshi pointed me to to do the following:

```
    public function makeRecursive($d, $r = 0, $pk = 'parent', $k = 'wo_number', $c = 'children') {
            $m = array();
            foreach ($d as $e) {
                    isset($m[$e[$pk]]) ?: $m[$e[$pk]] = array();
                    isset($m[$e[$k ]]) ?: $m[$e[$k ]] = array();
                    $m[$e[$pk]][] = array_merge($e, array($c => &$m[$e[$k]]));
            }
            $final = array(
                    'wo_number'=>$r,
                    'leaf'=>false,
                    'children'=>$m[$r]
            );
            return $final;
    }
```

And this solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

I has the same problem and its very simple resolved under javascript after data received by store extension for struct `{DictDataArray: [{Id, parentId, Name}]}`

```
appendRawData: function(data){
            var me = this;
            var rNode = me.getRootNode();
            data = (Ext.isString(data) && Ext.decode(data)) || data;
            function ParentFilter(element, index, array){
                return element.ParentId == this.filterId;
            };

            function BuildTree(list, filter){
                var tmp = list.filter(ParentFilter, filter);
                if(tmp && tmp.length)
                {
                    var node= (filter.filterId && me.getById(filter.filterId)) || rNode;
                    node && node.appendChild && node.appendChild(tmp);
                }
                for(var item in tmp){
                    BuildTree(list, {filterId: tmp[item].Id});
                    var node= me.getById(tmp[item].Id);
                    node.set('leaf', !node.hasChildNodes());
                }
            };
            data && data.DictDataResult && BuildTree(data.DictDataResult, {filterId: null});
        },
```

and after load simple call

```
store.appendRawData(response)
```

but other way is create own reader and represent data into loadData by overloaded this function that read raw data and transform it as you need