# Deleting a item from multilevel category or menu list

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, categories, sql-delete

I am making Categories system management like WordPress.

As you can see in my database if i delete (or updating delete to 1) a category. All its child disappear fro the list.

[image: Database]

Before delete ->
[image: Before delete category list]

After delete ->
[image: After delete category list]

But this not happening in the WordPress case. It deletes the selected category and assign its child to the parent of deleted category.
I want to do the same.

Step 1 -> get the parent of category which will be deleted.

Step 2 -> update parent field of all child's of selected category with the id which we will get from from step 1.

Step 3 -> delete the selected category.

Am i right?
Is there any other way or shorter way to do that?

I think wordpress id doing the same
A comment from taxonomy.php wordpress file (function wp_delete_term)

```
/**
         * Fires immediately after a term to delete's children are reassigned a parent.
         *
         * @since 2.9.0
         *
         * @param array $edit_tt_ids An array of term taxonomy IDs for the given term.
         */
```

A workaround, may help some other users or devs, if you have any another or other solution, please let me know.

Getting categories from Database ->

Array "m" stores the proper shorted categories.

"m2" stores the Parent Cat id as key and its Children ids as value.

```
if (!function_exists('_get_categories')) {

function _get_categories($key = 0, $parent = 'term_parent', $db_key = 'term_id', $child = 'children', $child_id = 'children_id') {

  $CI =& get_instance();

  $m = array();
  $m1 = array();

                                    $cat_query   = $CI->db->get_where('terms', array(
            'term_active' => 1,
            'term_delete' => 0,
            'term_type' => 'category'
        ));
     $input_data = $cat_query->result_array();


  foreach ($input_data as $data) {
    if($data['term_parent']==-null)
    {
    $data['term_parent']=0; 
    }

    if(!isset($m[$data[$parent]])) 
    {
        $m[$data[$parent]] = array();

    }


    if(!isset($m[$data[$db_key]]))
    {
         $m[$data[$db_key]] = array();

    }

    if(isset($m1[$data['term_parent']][$child_id]))
    {
    $m1[$data['term_parent']][$child_id] = $m1[$data['term_parent']][$child_id].','.$data['term_id'];
    }
    else{
        $m1[$data['term_parent']][$child_id] = ','.$data['term_id'];
    }

    $m[$data[$parent]][] = array_merge($data, array($child => &$m[$data[$db_key]]));

}

return(array($m[$key],$m1));

}

}
```

Now printing categories list properly ->

```
function nested($data,$child_ids,$level,$urls) {

  if (sizeof($data) > 0) {

    foreach ($data as $entry) {
    $childern_ids ="";
    if(isset($child_ids[$entry['term_id']]['children_id']))
    {
        $childern_ids = $child_ids[$entry['term_id']]['children_id'];
    }

     ?>
<tr role="row" class="odd">
                                        <td>
                                            <label>
                                            <?php echo form_checkbox('category_active_table_checkbox_singal[]',$entry['term_id'].','.$entry['term_parent'].''.$childern_ids, false, array('class'=>'category_active_table_checkbox_singal')); ?>
                                            </label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td class="sorting_1">
                                        <?php

         for($i=1;$i<$level;$i++)
         {
             echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
         }

        ?>
        -- <?php echo $entry['term_name']; ?></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php echo $entry['term_time']; ?></td>
                                        <td>
                                           <a href="<?php echo $urls['category_edit_url'].'?category_id='.$entry['term_id']; ?>">Edit</a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>       
                                    <?php
        nested($entry['children'],$child_ids,$level+1,$urls);

    }

  }


}



nested($active_category_records[0],$active_category_records[1],1,$urls);
```

Here nested function parameters.
1. Data (return m), 2. Child array (return m1), 3. Space level, 4. My custom need

Processing file -> (delete file)

```
 $category_ids        = $this->input->post('category_active_table_checkbox_singal[]');
        $action_type     = $this->input->post('table_multi_action_active_category_action_type');
        $from_hidden_url = $this->input->post('return_url');


       $cat_array = explode(",", $category_ids[0]);
      echo $cat_id = $cat_array[0];
       echo $cat_parent_id = $cat_array[1];


$data = array(
       'term_parent' => $cat_parent_id
);
$where = array (
'term_parent' => $cat_id
);

$this->Category_model->category_update($data,$where);

$data1 = array(
       'term_delete' => 1,
       'term_active' => 0
);
$where1 = array (
'term_id' => $category_ids[0]
);
$this->Category_model->category_update($data1,$where1);
```

Here you can do whatever you want, Twist here is you also getting "Parent ID" and its "Children IDs" without any database query. Use explode and do anything

Comment: Is there any difference between a content management system (e.g. WordPress) and a categories system management (e.g. the one you're doing)?!

Comment: @Sheedo, My category management system may be similar to wordpress category management system (in view only), but database structure may be different

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry nothing to do with that, sorry, my question is different ithink