# Building multi-dimensional array from rowset

Tags: php, mysql, tree, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create multi-dimensional array from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884337/how-to-create-multi-dimensional-array-from-a-list)
>   [PHP Create a Multidimensional Array from an array with relational data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239652/php-create-a-multidimensional-array-from-an-array-with-relational-data)

I currently have a parent-child model in my database. The table looks like this:

```
id         int  
parent_id  int
text       int
```

Assuming I've done the `SELECT *` query to retrieve all the columns on this table, how exactly would I go about building a multi-dimensional array from this result set, where each array contains an array of children where the parent_id is equal to the rows id.

Sample data:

```
id   parent_id   text
1     NULL       Blah1
2     1          Blah 2 
3     2          Blah3
4     1          Blah 4
```

Finally, once that array is built, how would you iterate through it to print out the tree like indented structure?

```
Blah1 
    Blah2
        Blah3
    Blah4
```

Your help is most appreciated.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11497724/1446794)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$items = array(
    array('id' => 1, 'parent_id' => null, 'text'=>'text'),
    array('id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 1 , 'text'=>'text'),
    array('id' => 3, 'parent_id' => 2, 'text'=>'text'),
    array('id' => 4, 'parent_id' => 1 , 'text'=>'text'),
);

$childs = array();

foreach($items as $item)
  $childs[$item['parent_id']][] = $item;

foreach($items as $item) if (isset($childs[$item['id']]))
  $item['childs'] = $childs[$item['id']];

$tree = $childs[0];

var_dump($tree);
```